# Show other array in next view controller depending on button pressed in previous

Tags: ios, swift

I spent hours to make this work but I am trying to show an array in a view controller based on the button that is pressed in the previous view. So I want to use the same view controller but with different data.

In the view controller:

```
@IBAction func firstDeck(_ sender: UIButton) {
var dataSource : CardsDataModel? {

    didSet {
        label.text = cardsDeck.FirstDate()
        } 
    }
}

@IBAction func secondDeck(_ sender: UIButton) {
var dataSource : CardsDataModel? {

            didSet {
           label.text = cardsDeck.PizzaFriends()
         }
    }
}
```

So there are two cardDecks: PizzaFriends and FirstDates. I tried using IBAction from the buttons to then show the relevant cardsDeck but without success. The cards are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an Array of String type variable in **NextViewController**

```
var someData = [String]()
```

In `viewDidLoad()` method of **NextViewController** add this

```
print("Some Data: \(someData)")
```

In the **PreviousViewController** in the IBAction methods present/push the **NextViewController** with assign `someText` variable according to which button has been pressed

```
@IBAction func firstDeck(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = NextViewController()
    vc.someData = cardsDeck.FirstDate()

    // If you want to present NextViewController
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // If you want to push NextViewController to navigation stack
    //navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func secondDeck(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = NextViewController()
    vc.someData = cardsDeck.PizzaFriends()

    // If you want to present NextViewController
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // If you want to push NextViewController to navigation stack
    //navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Here is a sample **NextViewController**

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    var someData = [String]()

    var cardView = SwipeCardView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 150, width: 300, height: 600))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        self.view.addSubview(cardView)

        cardView.label.text = "\(someData)"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mussaddique Billah Talha Thanks for your reply! I am trying to get the output within a View that lives in the NextViewController. I can't use the print but have to work with "label.text =". I tried "label.text = showData", no errors but blank cards. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: you need to set the label in viewDidLoad of NextViewController and not in the previous controller.

Comment: @chirag90 Thanks for your help. It is in the next Controller, but in a View of that controller and thus not in the controller file but the view file (I need to make it work with "label.text = ". Thanks

Comment: Is your view an xib file ?

Comment: @chirag90 A standard Swift file. 'let vc = ViewController()

        var dataSource : CardsDataModel? {

        didSet {
            label.text = vc.showData
            }
        }' does not work

Comment: Done everything as suggested, but I receive this error: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Do you connect your label (IBOutlet) with Storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MusaddiqueBillahTalha! I use a storyboard. My PreviousViewController (initial) is visual and my NextViewController is all code. So I have connected the buttons in the PVC but not the label in the NVC. In there I use a View that basically needs this: "text = (someData)" but that's not working. Thanks

Comment: Could you please upload your project somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample NVC which is created in code. Please check it.

Comment: @MusaddiqueBillahTalha Thanks so much. Here is the view in which I want to place the label. I cannot seem to place it directly into the NextViewController, but instead need to place it into this View: https://codeshare.io/anVZ1n

Comment: In your **SwipeCardView** class change `override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }` to `override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }` . I updated the answer again. Please check it.

Comment: @MusaddiqueBillahTalha I am getting there, thanks. At least I get one String from the array. Now it's blocked by this "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[CardsDataModel]'" for line "vc.viewModelData = cardsDeck.FirstDate()" 

Code of CardsDataModel: https://codeshare.io/2BYe4m

Comment: change `vc.viewModelData = cardsDeck.FirstDate()` to `let cardsData = cardsDeck.FirstDate()
vc.viewModelData = cardsData.text`

Comment: @MusaddiqueBillahTalha Get an error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'text'" I updated the codeshare to show you more of the project. Trying to make line 65 work, but get the error on line 8 and 20. https://codeshare.io/2BYe4m

Comment: What's the Data Type of `cardsDeck.FirstDate()`?

Comment: I think `cardsDeck.FirstDate()` is String. Change `var viewModelData = [CardsDataModel(text: String())]` to `var viewModelData = ""` at line 65. I hope it will work.

Comment: @MusaddiqueBillahTalha really close now. Two things: 
1. Warning: Attempt to present ViewController on PreviousViewController which is already presenting ViewController. So the second deck: PizzaFriend is not showing, only the first FirstDate. 

2. It only shows 1 string, but it does show the right amount of cards and is repeating it. I need it to show a variety of strings. This is because of the change I had to make on line 130 (it expects an array, but gets a single string I think)

Thanks again!

Comment: Issue One: I think you do not dismiss the ViewController at any point of App lifecycle.

Comment: Issue Two: could you please upload the code of `SwipeCardsDataSource` class?

Comment: @MusaddiqueBillahTalha Thanks, I added it to the codeshare https://codeshare.io/2BYe4m

Comment: @MusaddiqueBillahTalha Thanks thus far! I think your solution answers my question, it's just I ran into new challenges. What happens is that it repeats the same String in the deck of cards instead of presenting a new String on every new card. (The [index] gives me an error) Just to give you a visual insight: https://dsh.re/8bc66.